# How to send Jenkins console logs into Elastic?

Tags: elasticsearch, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, open-telemetry

I'm trying to build a post-build in Jenkins pipelines so that every time a failure happens I want to send the console log error into Elastic so I can track how often an error happens or similar things. I have different declarative pipelines like Freestyle, Multibranch. I have been looking [OpenTelemntry](https://github.com/jenkinsci/opentelemetry-plugin/blob/master/docs/build-logs.md#can-the-jenkins-server-logs-and-the-logs-of-other-types-of-jobs-like-freestyle-or-matrix-jobs-be-sent-through-opentelemetry-to-be-stored-outside-of-jenkins) plugin but this doesn't support Freestyle jobs.

**Is there any way that I can get console logs in Jenkinsfile and send it into Elastic with cURL command for example?**

Comment: You can access Jenkins console log via following URL `${BUILD_URL}/consoleText`. You can save output to file or send raw data to Elastic.
I would not be able to provide specific command how to send it since I am not Elastic expert.

Comment: @MichałLewndowski by using the command you suggested I'm able to see the console logs. But I don't know how to send this into Elastic because I'm new to Elastic anyway, Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just wanted to post this maybe it will help someone who can come across for an answer. It turns out that using the `OpenTelemtry` plugin in Jenkis to send the logs in Elastic was a very good decision and everyone liked it. This page [OpenTelemetry](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/observability/current/ci-cd-observability.html) can give an overview of how it looks and how you can make `OpenTelementry` work with Jenkins.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34899644)